# Invertible operator with countable spectrum

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory

Let $H$ be  a separable  Hilbert space  and $A$ is  an invertible  bounded operator on $H$. Can we approximate  $A$ with  an invertible operator $B$ such that $sp(B)$ is  a countable set?

**Motivation:**

If the answer is yes, this  would give's us  an alternative  proof  of  connected ness of $GL(H)$. This  alternative proof is identical to a short and interesting proof  of  connectedness  of  $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$, in page  19 of "Introduction to the  Baums  Connes conjecture" by Alain Valette

Comment: Should the inverse also be bounded?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta  yes all things are  bounded operators?

Comment: Ok. The inverse of a bounded invertible operator need not be bounded, so I wanted to check.

Comment: Hmm... In a complex Hilbert space you can write $A=B+iC$ with $B$ and $C$ selfadjoint, and selfadjoint operators are easy to approximate since they diagonalize. I don't know what happens for invertibility and the spectrum of the sum though.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta I don't understand your comment about inverses, unless you are dealing with densely-defined operators. In the case of bounded operators on a Banach space we have the Banach isomorphism theorem, unless I have misread or misunderstood something

Comment: @YemonChoi, I mean everywhere defined operators. Invertibility is not so important, spectrum is the main point. I was just wondering if one could use countable spectrum approximations for $B$ and $C$ to build one for $A$ and if this approximation would be invertible if the first ones were (since invertibility was asked for).

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta My confusion is: you said above "The inverse of a bounded invertible operator need not be bounded" and the Banach isomorphism theorem tells us that actually, this is always the case

Comment: @YemonChoi, a bounded invertible operator need not be surjective or have closed range. Consider for example the operator on $\ell^2(\mathbb N)$ that divides the $n$th coordinate by $n$. It is surely injective and so has an inverse, but the inverse is not continuous. Maybe the confusion is that for me invertible means injective and for you bijective, so my invertible is your left invertible.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta yes, my confusion was precisely this difference of terminology. But I am fairly sure the OP uses my definition of "invertible"

Comment: @YemonChoi  Yes By invertible I mean bijective. So as you said, the inverse is  bounded, by open mapping theorem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the answer is "no"; here is a sketch of an argument though I will have to go back and check the details. First, there is nothing special about invertibility here; if every invertible operator is approximable by operators with countable spectrum, then every operator is, just by translation. I claim the unilateral shift $S$ should not be approximable, because it is a Fredholm operator of nonzero index. The set of Fredholm operators is open, and the index is a continuous function on this set, so any sufficiently good approximant would have to be Fredholm of index -1. But I *think* that if a Fredholm operator has countable spectrum, then the index must be 0 (reason: if 0 is not isolated in the spectrum, then the range won't be closed, and if 0 is isolated (or the operator is invertible) then the index is clearly 0).

**EDIT:** Here is a proof that a Fredholm operator $T$ with countable spectrum must have index 0. We may clearly suppose $T$ is not invertible, so 0 is in the spectrum. The first claim is that 0 must be isolated--if not, then since the spectrum is a countable, compact set, 0 must be the limit of a sequence of *isolated* points in the spectrum. But each isolated point must be an eigenvalue, which means that $T$ would then have a sequence of eigenvalues tending to 0, and would not have closed range and not be Fredholm. So, 0 is isolated. But then $T+\epsilon I$ is invertible for all small $\epsilon$, and by the continuity of the index we have that $ind(T)=0$.

Comment: thank you very much for your interesting answer. I have  a question on your statement "Isolated points are eigenvalue" In this  statement, is not necessary that we assume T is normal?

Comment: I thought this should just follow from the Fredholm assumption and the Riesz functional calculus, but perhaps it is more subtle than that. Let me think about it some more.

Comment: OK, I no longer trust my claim about eigenvalues; however it is true that if 0 is in the *boundary* of the spectrum of a Fredholm operator (which is of course the case here), then it must be isolated and the operator must have index 0. This follows from a theorem of Putnam; see Conway's "A Course in Functional Analysis", Theorems XI.6.8 and XI.6.9.

Comment: Thank you very much for your beautiful answer and your reference to Putnam theorem. However, regarding the eigenvalue  problem, i think that $I+V$ is  a counter example where $V$ is the Voltra integral operator. It has  a  single spectrum $\{1\}$ which is not eigenvalue.

Answer (score 8):

The question has already been answered above (by Mike Jury). Here is another way of arguing: Any operator with countable spectrum is in the closure of the invertible operators. So are their limits. But again, the unilateral shift provides an example of an operator not in the closure of the invertibles. For if $\|S-X\|<1$ then $\|I-S^*X\|<1$, and so $S^*X$ is invertible. $X$ cannot be invertible, since otherwise $S^*$ would also be invertible. So no translate $S+\lambda I$ can be approximated by operators with countable spectrum.

Comment: Nice! Indeed, this shows that if $\|S - X\| = a < 1$ then the spectrum of $X$ contains ${\rm ball}(0;1-a)$.

Comment: Very nice! More elegant than my answer, clearly.

Comment: @LeonelRobert Thanks  for  your  answer. Assume that $S^{*}X$ is invertible. How  you conclude that $S^{*}$ is  not right invertible/(How you obtained  a contradiction?0

Comment: @AliTaghavi. The argument shows that $X$ within a distance less than 1 from $S$ cannot be invertible. For if it were, that together with $S^*X$ being invertible would imply that $S^*$ is invertible (which is not).

Answer (score 3):

It is well-known that you can approximate a **selfadjoint** operator $A$ with an operator $B=A+V$ such that $B$ has pure point spectrum. The selfadjoint operator $V$ can have arbitrarily small Hilbert-Schmidt norm.

This is a theorem of Weyl-von Neumann and can be found e.g. in Kato.

But I don't think this works for the nonselfadjoint case.

EDIT: Christian Remling mentioned and is right, of course, that the point spectrum of $B$ has to be dense in the continuous spectrum of $A$ since the essential spectrum is conserved. 
So the pure point spectrum  of $B$ don't have to be countable.

Comment: The spectrum of $B$ is the closure of the eigenvalues, so this won't give countable spectrum. Quite on the contrary, you know that the essential spectrum is preserved.

Comment: On the other hand, it is easy to give an approximation directly if $A$ is self-adjoint: just approximate $\int_I t\, dE(t)$ by a suitable multiple of the identity on $E(I)$ for small intervals $I$, and put these pieces back together to obtain $B$. (This $B$ will have finite spectrum.)